# Linux keyboard macro X11

Tags: linux, keyboard, xorg

I'm using debian linux with X11 and dwm as a window manager. I have an application that make me press the same key three times in a row, I want to automate this, so instead of pressing  three times I would only have to press F1 (or any other key) once.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to suggest `autokey` or `xbindkeys`.

The [`autokey`](https://code.google.com/p/autokey/) has GTK and QT GUIs, it supports python scripts and text pasting.

The [`xbindkeys`](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeys.html) is a more low-level thing, but you may prefer it since you decided to use dwm. I can't find a good how-to for Debian, so here is an [article on Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys), it should give an idea of how to use it.

Both tools allow to execute some commands or scripts, but actually they can't repeat *keystrokes* out of the box. If you need to send some keyboard events to the X server (which is different from pasting some text), then you can use [`xdotool`](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml) in combination with autokey or xbindkeys.

All these tools are available in the official Debian repositories, so it is easy to install them with `apt-get`.

Comment: Thanks, xdotool seems to do the job, xbindkeys can be replaced by dwm

Comment: autokey on its own worked well for me for sending key-presses. In scripts, `keyboard.send_key("<down>")` can be used to send the down arrow key, for example. See the included example scripts.